# Android - In-line autocomplete with EditText

Tags: android, autocomplete, search-engine

I want to get an in-line autocomplete with an EditText, not a result list but the best suggestion directly in EditText.
Something like this : [In-line auto-complete](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-auto-complete-text-field) (near the bottom of the page).

Is it possible in Android ?
Thank you.

Comment: You can add a watcher on the EditText and show any widget in the view.

Comment: Can you be more explicit ?

Comment: Put an example of what you need first. If you need a custom component (check AutoCompleteTextView first) you can add a watch to you edittext. The watch tells you when the input by the user has changed so you can call a service to load suggested entries. Check this url developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: I haven't got enough reputation to post an image... But in my previous link you can see an example (in in-line auto-complete section). Ok, but what service call to show suggestion with different color in EditText ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no eclipse now so I will try to give you some hints.

To create a custom autocomplete I would do something like this.

### First

In the view layout add the EditText and an OutputText (this with visibility=hidden)

### Second

In the activity create a TextWatcher and implement the method afterTextChanged.

Inside this method call a service with the  input text and then update the content of the outputText.

Something like:

```
afterTextChanged(Editable s){
  // you know your input is an EditText
  final EditText input= (EditText) s;
  // TODO make this call async
  String suggestedText= someService.getSuggestion(input.getString());
  outputText.setText(suggestedText);
  outputText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  // to avoid infinite loops
  if(suggestedText!=null && !"".equals(suggestedText) && !suggestedText.equals(input.getString())
  {
    // add a onclick control to update the input
    outputText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        editText.setText(suggestedText);
    });
  }

}
```

### Third

Implement the suggestion service.

Answer (score 0):

Android has an `AutoCompleteTextView` which should do the job you want.

According to the official Android docs

"`AutoCompleteTextView` is an editable text view that shows completion suggestions automatically while the user is typing. The list of suggestions is displayed in a drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the content of the edit box with.

The drop down can be dismissed at any time by pressing the back key or, if no item is selected in the drop down, by pressing the enter/dpad center key.

The list of suggestions is obtained from a data adapter and appears only after a given number of characters defined by the threshold."

For an example code snippet refer to [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Fareya, i've already seen AutoCompleteTextView but i don't want to have a list. Only one result displayed in EditText like a hint. My previous link show a short example (section in-line auto-complete).

Answer (score 0):

For autocomplete you must another type of EditText called AutocompleteTextView or MultiAutocompleteTextView. [Here](http://android-helper.blogspot.com/2013/07/simple-autocompletetextview-example.html) you can find simple example for that option.

P.S. if you want to create your own type of List Filtration, your Adapter class must implement [Filterable](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html) interface